# Marking nodes of a complete binary tree

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees, randomized-algorithms, colorings

Suppose that I have a binary tree with $N = 2^h - 1$ nodes, initially all nodes are *unmarked* Over time via this process nodes became marked.
Suppose that nodes have unique identifiers in range of $[1,N]$ each time, I *send* you the identifier of a node. when you receive a sent node. you mark it and also invoke the following *marking rule*, which takes effect before I send out next node.

- If a node and its sibling are marked, its parent is marked.
- If a node and its parent are marked, the other sibling is marked.

The marking rule is applied *recursively as much as possible* before the next node is sent.

**Process 1** : each unit of time, I send the identifier of a node chosen *independently and uniformly at random from all of the N nodes*.

**Process 2**: each unit of time I send the identifier of a node chosen uniformly at random from those nodes *that I have not yet sent*.

**Process 3**: each unit of time I send the identifier of a node chosen uniformly from those nodes *that you have not yet marked*.

1. For the first process, prove that the expected number of nodes sent is $\Omega(N \log N)$
2. For the second process, you should find that almost all $N$ nodes must be sent before the tree is marked. Show that , with a constant probability, at leas $N - 2 \sqrt N$ nodes must be sent.
3. The behavior of the third process might seem a bit unusual. Explain it with a proof.

I need some hint how to proceed to analyze this process ??

Comment: This seems to be a programming question and so out of scope here.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I edited the question to suit this website.

Comment: @HadiAmiri But there's no question in your... question.